# Задать значение width используя var

Tags: css, jquery, width

Нужно подогнать картинку с ширной 7000px под экран, при этом неважно какой размер у экрана.

Думаю делать через jQuery, но этот код не работает:

```js
$(".img1 img").width($(window).width());
```

Как можно решить?

Comment: А просто стиль `width: 100vw` без всяких скриптов?

Answer (score 0):

Удали `'.img1'` и повесь на `img` другой класс, а также вытаскивай ширину `body`. Получится как-то так:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("img").width($("body").width());
});
```

Потыкать можно на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dan-sazonov/pen/xxgvaWr).
Кстати, можно обойтись только CSS:

```css
.img1 img {
    width: 100vw;
}
```